# No input file specified; I get this when i try to launch my web site into my browser

Tags: vagrant, homestead

Im trying to launch my website on my local host but every time i time the domain (Whoodie.dev:8000)into my browser I get "no input file specified" on my screen.
This is my homestead.yaml file I think thats were the problem lay. Can anybody help me or point me in the right direction?

ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/www
      to: /home/vagrant/www

sites:
    - map: Whoodie.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/www/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV 
      value: local

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like nginx is struggling to find the location that you've told it to load from.

If you `vagrant ssh` into the box and run `cd /home/vagrant/Code/www/Laravel/public` does it exist?

If not, assuming your folder structure inside `~/www` is actually `~/www/Code/Laravel/public` then your mapping should be:

`sites: - map: Whoodie.dev to: /home/vagrant/www/Code/Laravel/public`

Try changing that then run `vagrant provision` and see if that helps.